# JFrame opens only the close, minimize and resize buttons until I resize the window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm making a game in Java and the game window doesn't open properly when i run the code. I can resize it and make it the right size, but that's kinda annoying to do every time.

Here's the code for the window and I also added a picture to show how the window opens.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends Canvas {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 573860602378245302L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your `Game` class ?

Comment: 1) **Change `frame.add(game); frame.setVisible(true);` to `frame.add(game); frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);`** 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) It's much more likely that the size of the **`Game`** needs to be fixed to a particular `width` and `height`. The frame should then be packed to fit it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, the first option helped me.

Comment: *"the first option helped me"* You're welcome. Please note the MCVE / SSCCE advice for the future. And a tip: Add @MaifeeUlAsad (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Yes, i will pay more attention to that in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can make a `JFrame` of a particular size. `frame.setPreferredSize()` is NOT one of those ways.

You can call `setSize(int width, int height)` on `JFrame` like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JFrameSize
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Or you can set preferred size of the contents (a `JPanel` in below example) of `JFrame` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class JFrameSize2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```